# Configure Git with SSH for Phabricator

Tags: git, ssh, phabricator

I'm trying to configure SSH for Phabricator to get git running. I've followed this [manual](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/diffusion_hosting/#configuring-ssh) but when I call `echo {} | ssh git@phabricator.mydomain.com conduit conduit.ping` I always get an empty result or `Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).`.

**`/etc/ssh-phabricator/sshd_config`**:

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/libexec/ssh-phabricator-hook
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser git

Port 22
Protocol 2
PermitRootLogin no
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog no
PasswordAuthentication no
AuthorizedKeysFile none
```

**`/etc/passwd`**:

```
phd:x:999:999::/var/tmp/phd:/bin/false
git:x:1005:1005::/home/git:/bin/bash
```

**`/etc/shadow`**:

```
phd:!:16135::::::
git:NP:16135:0:99999:7:::
```

**`/etc/sudoers`**:

```
git ALL=(phd) SETENV: NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git-upload-pack, /usr/bin/git-receive-pack, /bin/false
```

**`~/.ssh/config`**:

```
Host phabricator.mydomain.com
    HostName phabricator.mydomain.com
    Port 22
    IdentityFile /c/Users/.../.ssh/id_rsa_phabricator
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    User git
```

**UPDATE**

The reasons for my problems were:

- I didn't use the SSH key with the client.
- I didn't ensure that the `git` user has a shell.

Comment: Some of the information in https://secure.phabricator.com/T4151 hasn't made it to the main documentation yet, but may be helpful. Particularly, check that your `git` user has `NP` (not `!!`) and a real shell like `/bin/sh` (not `/bin/false`) in `/etc/shadow`.

Comment: Thanks! This should be part of the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ssh hook is working properly - first, you should ensure that the git ssh user is able to ssh to the normal ssh daemon - this will ensure that you can login with this user.

More than likely you have a bad home directory or bad shell as stated in the comments.

If all of that is working fine, make sure you have a ssh key uploaded to your profile and that you are using this key to connect with.

Answer (score 3):

Just another thing to note is the path must have the correct permissions for the `AuthorizedKeysCommand` or this could also result in

```
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the

```
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)
```

problem too and found another cause that is not yet mentioned here: SELinux.

If you use SELinux with "Enforcing" policy on your server, you might run into the same problems. To check if SELinux is responsible, set

```
$ setenforce 0
```

and try

```
$ echo {} | ssh git@phabricator.mydomain.com conduit conduit.ping
```

again.

If it suddenly works, but you don't want to permanently disable SELinux or run it in permissive mode, you can use **audit2allow** to resolve the issues that your server recently encountered:

```
$ ausearch -m avc -ts recent | audit2allow -M local
$ semodule -i local.pp
```

This ausearch prints recent entries from the SELinux log (usually /var/log/audit/audit.log ) and audit2allow creates policies for entries that are marked as **denied**. 
Make sure there are no recent entries in the log you don't want to allow.