# Configure Git with Phabricator Permission Denied(publickey)

Tags: git, ssh, config, phabricator, sshd

**The issue**
when testing `echo {} | ssh -p -2222

```
C:>echo {} | ssh -p 2222 git@[redacted] conduit conduit.ping

git@[redacted]: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Running `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d -d -d -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator` On the server terminal. I have paegent running on the client computer with all private keys that I have in phabricator.

```
phd@Ubuntu-16:~$ sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d -d -d -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator
debug2: load_server_config: filename /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator
debug2: load_server_config: done config len = 353
debug2: parse_server_config: config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator len 353
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:6 setting AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/libexec/phabricator-ssh-hook.sh
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:7 setting AuthorizedKeysCommandUser git
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:8 setting AllowUsers git
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:13 setting Port 2222
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:14 setting Protocol 2
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:15 setting PermitRootLogin no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:16 setting AllowAgentForwarding no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:17 setting AllowTcpForwarding no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:18 setting PrintMotd no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:19 setting PrintLastLog no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:20 setting PasswordAuthentication no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:21 setting ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:22 setting AuthorizedKeysFile none
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:24 setting PidFile /var/run/sshd-phabricator.pid
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:hgTVy06V7xUYpl/ySO/QmryHXLc67o14j5PVldXwb/8
debug1: private host key #1: ssh-dss SHA256:vKutQKEFxkaq2jnDuaxqcjlGegKExe1J3pxJMp9Soq0
debug1: private host key #2: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:HGbKXRVY4yOtYUXIgm9p1kFzTbngdn7pr1+7Xxmw7ic
debug1: private host key #3: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:ImonslwBI2FFtd54a3V6hSqGlVNSv7Q/C53WSQ8qZn8
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-d'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='-d'
debug1: rexec_argv[4]='-f'
debug1: rexec_argv[5]='/etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator'
debug3: oom_adjust_setup
debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2222.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 4 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 2222.
debug3: fd 5 is not O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 8 config len 353
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: send_rexec_state: done
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from [client computer] port 56033 on [phabricator server] port 2222
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: ssh_sandbox_init: preparing seccomp filter sandbox
debug2: Network child is on pid 3534
debug3: preauth child monitor started
debug3: privsep user:group 110:65534 [preauth]
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 110/65534 [preauth]
debug3: ssh_sandbox_child: setting PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS [preauth]
debug3: ssh_sandbox_child: attaching seccomp filter program [preauth]
debug3: list_hostkey_types: ssh-dss key not permitted by HostkeyAlgorithms [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 20 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 20 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug2: local server KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug2: peer client KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c [preauth]
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: compression ctos: none [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 30 [preauth]
debug3: mm_key_sign entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 6 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 6
debug3: mm_answer_sign
debug3: mm_answer_sign: hostkey proof signature 0x7e18f0(100)
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 7
debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
debug3: mm_key_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 7 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 31 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 21 [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 7 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 21 [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 5 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 6 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user git service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 8 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 8
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow
debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 353
debug3: auth_shadow_acctexpired: today 17761 sp_expire -1 days left -17762
debug3: account expiration disabled
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow: sending MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM: 1
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 9
debug2: monitor_read: 8 used once, disabling now
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 9 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for git [preauth]
debug3: mm_inform_authserv entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 4 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 4
debug3: mm_answer_authserv: service=ssh-connection, style=, role=
debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none [preauth]
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey" [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
Connection reset by [client computer] port 56033 [preauth]
debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: Killing privsep child 3534
debug1: audit_event: unhandled event 12
```

**Setup**

Phabricator is ran by damenon user `phd` vcs-user is `git`. The base directory for phabricator is `/home/usr/phd/phabricator/`. OpenSSHD version `OpenSSH_7.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`.

**Phabricator specific ssh files**

/etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator

```
# NOTE: You must have OpenSSHD 6.2 or newer; support for AuthorizedKeysCommand
# was added in this version.

# NOTE: Edit these to the correct values for your setup.
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/libexec/phabricator-ssh-hook.sh
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser git
AllowUsers git

# You may need to tweak these options, but mostly they just turn off everything
# dangerous.

Port 2222
Protocol 2
PermitRootLogin no
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog no
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
AuthorizedKeysFile none

PidFile /var/run/sshd-phabricator.pid
~
```

/usr/libexec/phabricator-ssh-hook.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# NOTE: Replace this with the username that you expect users to connect with.
    VCSUSER="git"   

# NOTE: Replace this with the path to your Phabricator directory.
ROOT="/home/phd/phabricator"

if [ "$1" != "$VCSUSER" ];
then
  exit 1
fi

exec "$ROOT/bin/ssh-auth" $@
~
```

/etc/passwd

```
git:x:1001:1001:Git,,,:/home/git:/bin/bash
```

/etc/shadow

```
git:NP:17761:0:99999:7:::
```

/etc/sudoers

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
git ALL=(phd) SETENV: NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git-upload-pack, /usr/bin/git-receive-pack, /usr/bin/git
www-data ALL=(phd) SETENV: NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git-upload-pack, /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend, /usr/bin/git
```

Reviewing the suggestions [Configure Git with SSH for Phabricator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236640/configure-git-with-ssh-for-phabricator) did not help

I am unable to ssh directly onto the server using the vcs-usr `git` but that seems to be because in `/etc/shadow` git is `NP` per the phabricator docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pageant doesn't interact with ssh which was my first issue.
Second issue was i needed to `sudo chmod 775 /usr/libexec`.
third I needed to add the public key to my user settings -> ssh keys instead of the passphrase module.
Forth with pycharm i needed to change my git settings to built-in